# Python tkinter how to move up entry

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi guys I have this code

```
from tkinter import *
import os
class TechnologyIDE:
    def __init__(self, master):
        #Vytvoření master
        self.master = master
        master.title('Technology IDE')

        #Frame
        frame = Frame(root)
        frame.pack()

        self.frameLEFT = Frame(master)
        self.frameLEFT.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.frameRIGHT = Frame(master)
        self.frameRIGHT.pack(side=RIGHT)

        #Boxy
        self.showCodewitHLines()
        self.showProjectToolbar()
        self.showNavigator(


    def showProjectToolbar(self):
        screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
        width = int(screen_width/30)
        listbox = Listbox(self.frameLEFT)
        listbox.pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
        listbox.insert(END, "PROJECTS")
        listbox.insert(END, "   SOURCE")


    def showCodewitHLines(self):
        v = StringVar()
        e = Entry(self.frameRIGHT, textvariable=v)
        e.pack()

    def showNavigator(self):
        screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
        width = int(screen_width/30)
        listbox = Listbox(self.frameLEFT)
        listbox.pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
        listbox.insert(END, "NAVIGATOR")



root = Tk()
ide = TechnologyIDE(root)
root.mainloop()
```

the result looks like this
[image]

and I need that entry to be top, next to those boxes and fill the rest of space.
I setted up frameLEFT, frameRIGHT but it is as u see in the middle on other right side.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem instead of all your code. I don't want to read 200 lines to find the one where you pack the entry.

Comment: updated my question with lesser code, so its readable. If I knew where is mistake I would repair it myself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the `fill=Y` option to pack `self.frameLEFT` so that the two listboxes are at the top of the window (otherwise the height of `self.frameLEFT` would fit the two listboxes and `self.frameLEFT` would be centered vertically in the window).

For `self.frameRIGHT` I used `expand=True` and `fill=BOTH` so that it fills all the available space in the window.

Finally, for the entry `e`, I used `fill=X` so that it fills the available horizontal space.

```
from tkinter import *
import os
class TechnologyIDE:
    def __init__(self, master):
        #Vytvoření master
        self.master = master
        master.title('Technology IDE')

        #Frame
        frame = Frame(root)
        frame.pack()

        self.frameLEFT = Frame(master)
        self.frameLEFT.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)

        self.frameRIGHT = Frame(master)
        self.frameRIGHT.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=True, fill=BOTH)

        #Boxy
        self.showCodewitHLines()
        self.showProjectToolbar()
        self.showNavigator()


    def showProjectToolbar(self):
        screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
        width = int(screen_width/30)
        listbox = Listbox(self.frameLEFT)
        listbox.pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
        listbox.insert(END, "PROJECTS")
        listbox.insert(END, "   SOURCE")


    def showCodewitHLines(self):
        e = Text(self.frameRIGHT)
        e.pack(fill=BOTH)

    def showNavigator(self):
        screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
        width = int(screen_width/30)
        listbox = Listbox(self.frameLEFT)
        listbox.pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
        listbox.insert(END, "NAVIGATOR")


root = Tk()
ide = TechnologyIDE(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks m8 thats what I wanted but I need one more thing. I am trying to do IDE in python just to practice and partly 4fun. Can u tell me how to do mutliple lines user input ? this Entry that python tkinter has is only one line

Comment: You need to use a `Text` widget if you want multiline user input.